# How to make my displayString display my string

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to get my display string to show my objects. I'm new to javascript so its probably a simple answer!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayString(){

        var hunterLibrary = {
            "Title": "Hunter Library",
            "Latitude": 35.313316,
            "Longitude": -83.179788
        };

        var hFRBuilding = {
            "Title": "HFR Building",
            "Latitude": 35.308959,
            "Longitude": -83.186385
        };

        var downtownDillsboro = {
            "Title": "Downtown Dillsboro",
            "Latitude": 35.36949,
            "Longitude": -83.252764
        };


        displayString =
            "" + hunterLibrary.Title + "</b><br/>" +
            "Latitude: " + hunterLibrary.Latitude + "<br />" +
            "Longitude: " + hunterLibrary.Longitude + "<br />" +
            "" + hFRBuilding.Title + "</b><br/>" +
            "Latitude: " + hFRBuilding.Latitude + "<br />" +
            "Longitude: " + hFRBuilding.Longitude + "<br />" +
            "" + downtownDillsboro.Title + "</b><br/>" +
            "Latitude: " + downtownDillsboro.Latitude + "<br />" +
            "Longitude: " + downtownDillsboro.Longitude + "<p></p>";

        console.dir(hunterLibrary);
        console.dir(hFRBuilding);
        console.dir(downtownDillsboro);

        document.getElementById("divDisplay").innerHTML = displayString;

        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><b>Exercise 14: Creating and Using Javascript Objects</b></h1>
    <br />
    <div id="divDisplay"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I just need to have it display the string the second the page is loaded. At the moment it just shows the title and nothing else.

Comment: call your function after you make it- displayString()

Comment: you didn't declare `displayString` variable as a variable

Comment: and you didn't execute/call the `displayString()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let your `<script>` load the DOM first. Put the `<script>` under your `divDisplay`. The problem is the script cannot find where the div is and giving an error.

Second, avoid declaring same variable or function name.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<script>displayString()</script>` below `<div id="divDisplay"></div>`

```
<body>
    <h1><b>Exercise 14: Creating and Using Javascript Objects</b></h1>
    <br />
    <div id="divDisplay"></div>
    <script>displayString()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is calling your function. :) What you've done is declare that the function exists; you've taught the page *how* to display your string, but you've not actually asked it to do it.

Try

```
window.onload(function() { displayString() });
```

PS- Also, if you're just getting into javascript, go here: www.jquery.com and learn it. I taught myself to code (I am still pretty amateur in some respects) and for a long time put aside learning libraries, thinking to myself "I have to learn to do this the right way...". As an academic excercise, yes, learn your fundamentals. But if you want to actually get something done, go learn jQuery, because all the things the internet has taught you about what javascript can do in the last 5-8 years were really the things jQuery and similar libraries can do. You *could* build all your own bricks and then build your house, but not if you also want to live in it before you're old. ;)

### UPDATE

Try this version of your function; it's cleaner and easier to account for having small typos (which, if after calling the function properly, is most likely your answer):

```
function displayString(){
    var buildings = {
hunterLibrary:{
        "Title": "Hunter Library",
        "Latitude": 35.313316,
        "Longitude": -83.179788
    },
    hFRBuilding: {
        "Title": "HFR Building",
        "Latitude": 35.308959,
        "Longitude": -83.186385
    },
    downtownDillsboro: {
        "Title": "Downtown Dillsboro",
        "Latitude": 35.36949,
        "Longitude": -83.252764
    }
    };

    // save saves you the typing, and easier to debug
    var EOL = "</b><br />"
    var lat = "latitude";
    var long ="longitude";
    var displayString = '';

    for (b in buldings) {
        displayString += b.Title + EOL + lat + b.Latitude + EOL + long + b.Longitude + EOL;
    };

    document.getElementById("divDisplay").innerHTML = displayString;
    console.dir(buildings);
}
```

And you document should go:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <!---- all your page ------>
<script>
   //the function
  window.onload( displayString() );
</script>
```

Comment: so where would I put window.onload(displayString()); ? I put it before and after the function and it doesnt work.

Comment: And as for why it matters where you script goes, it's because the browser will load the page literally in order; your function can't be called before it exists, and it can't make demands of "divDisplay" until it, too, exists. Cheers.